# How can I enforce a judgement against an LLC owned by minors in PA?

Tags: small-claims-court, pennsylvania

How can I sue an LLC owned by minors in PA, after a court order to pay has been ignored?

I sued an LLC I was renting a house from because I did not receive my security deposit back when I moved.  I was granted a judgement was for me, and the LLC was ordered to pay me $550.00.  Now the people running the LLC are trying to hide behind the fact that the LLC is owned by their 2 minor children (ages 5 and 3 years old). How can I sue the LLC to comply with the court order?

Comment: If you have a judgment you don't need to sue again.  Are the parents certain they want you to hire a sheriff or constable to scare the pants off their little children, fiinding them (with the whole lights and sirens show) to serve a "debtors examination" or "writ of execution"?

Comment: They believe they are protected because the company is not in their name, we even had a problem in the first law suit about the name on the court papers, Because I put the order in the fathers name and not the company name, they wanted to case dropped and refiled and judge did an Amendment that day and proceeded with the hearing and they were very upset about that, they are trying to hide behind the fact that is an LLC and not in their names,

Comment: How can an LLC be "owned" by minors??

Comment: Any time you get this in front of a judge, they're going to be enormously irritated at the parents.  They aren't idiots, and they hate these sorts of games.

Comment: But you do have a judgment in hand today against "kidz, LLC"?

Comment: Yes there is a judgment against the LLC, the judge gave them 30 days to pay, they only have 7 days left and I have not received payment yet,

Comment: Well after the seven days are up, you can presumably take steps to collect the money from the LLC by getting the money from their bank account or putting a lien on the property.

Comment: @Scott: LLC can be owned by anyone. It must be run by adults. It has to pay what it owes. But it protects the owners from liability, whether they are children or adults. So the fact that the owners are children are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

[PA Code Title 26, Chapter 400](http://www.pacode.com/secure/data/246/chapter400/chap400toc.html) details the process for enforcing a judgement.  (A quick search turns up [more accessible summaries](http://pghfirm.com/pennsylvania-debt-collection-blog/how-to-collect-a-judgment-in-pennsylvania/).)  Unfortunately you'll almost certainly have to post some money for the process to proceed.  But if the process succeeds in recovering any assets your costs are paid out of the recovery.

The fact that the LLC is owned by minors is irrelevant.  You can directly collect against any assets of the LLC.

Granted, if the owners were very clever, they may have structured things so that the LLC does not have any assets, or so that they can pull its assets before you can get your hands on them.  But as one commentator noted: Local judges and sheriffs tend not to appreciate such legal shenanigans, so if they evade a judgement using their children you might appeal for further guidance to the judge who gave the order, or the sheriff you enlist to seize their property.

Comment: @feetwet presumably the LLC owns the house in question.